# Dygraphs not showing value

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm rewriting a site that I made purely in PHP to a straight Javascript implementation.  I moved all of my dygraphs code over, and the graph doesn't seem to show the value that you're hovering on anymore.  The only thing that I can think of that is different, is that in the previous version, I used a PHP array, made a string out of it, and echo'ed it into a  tag within my dygraph data declaration.  In the new version, I'm using a native array call for the data.  Might the formatters be screwing up here?  The graph itself shows up, so it seems like the data is working.

I also noticed that the dygraphs Titles and Axes labels aren't showing up in the new one, despite the same code.

Old implementation:

```
g = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("graphdiv"),    
[[],[],[]....],   //The whole array declaration couldn't be pasted here. Too big. 
    {

    labels: labels.slice(),
    title: 'cFIREsim Simulation Cycles',
    ylabel: 'Portfolio ($)',
    xlabel: 'Year',
    labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
    labelsDivWidth: 500,
    labelsDiv: 'labelsdiv',
    digitsAfterDecimal: 0,
    yAxisLabelWidth: 100,
    axes: {
        y: {
                labelsKMB: false,
                maxNumberWidth: 11,
                valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return 'Portfolio: $' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return '$' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }
        },
        x: {
            valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return 'Selected Year: ' + x;
                },
        },
    },
    showLabelsOnHighlight: true,
    highlightCircleSize: 3,
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    strokeBorderWidth: 0,
 highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: 1.0,
    highlightSeriesOpts: {
      strokeWidth: 4,
      strokeBorderWidth: 2,
      highlightCircleSize: 5,
    },
}
);
```

New Implementation:

```
Simulation.g.push(new Dygraph(
        // containing div
        document.getElementById("graph" + Simulation.tabs), //graph div has dynamic name for multiple graphs.
        chartData, {
            labels: labels.slice(),
            title: 'cFIREsim Simulation Cycles',
            ylabel: 'Portfolio ($)',
            xlabel: 'Year',
            labelsDivStyles: {
                'textAlign': 'right'
            },
            labelsDivWidth: 500,
            labelsDiv: 'labels' + this.tabs, //same dynamic names as graphdiv
            digitsAfterDecimal: 0,
            axes: {
                y: {
                    axisLabelWidth: 100,
                    labelsKMB: false,
                    maxNumberWidth: 11,
                    valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                        return 'Spending: $' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                    },
                    axisLabelFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                        return '$' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                        return 'Year: ' + x;
                    },
                },
            },
            showLabelsOnHighlight: true,
            highlightCircleSize: 3,
            strokeWidth: 1.5,
            strokeBorderWidth: 0,
            highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: 1.0,
            highlightSeriesOpts: {
                strokeWidth: 4,
                strokeBorderWidth: 2,
                highlightCircleSize: 5,
            },
        }
    ));
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in the JavaScript console?

Comment: As with 50% of my stackoverflow questions, I finally came up with a really stupid answer.  By default, the title, and values were white text, which were invisible on my white background.  I changed the CSS class for the labels to color: black, and it's all good.  Sigh. 

Thanks for the response anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a silly CSS issue. The labels div needed a CSS class so that I could actually SEE the labels on my black background.

```
.labels { color: black; }
```